Is it possible to request a xls/csv file as payload to chatgpt via API?
I have simple sheet with some financial data like Date, Category, Amount, Name, Tag for personal expenses control.
My idea is to provide some questions about this sheet and chatgpt give me answers (eg. give me the 3 most expenses of this month?
I've been searching for how to send this .xls, however, I have not find any example like this.
Currently, I'm converting the xls as json beautified and send it as part of the prompt, but it seems weird.
Anyone have any example on how to attach and send?
response = openai.chat.completions.create(
    model="gpt-4o",
    messages=[
        {"role": "system", "content": "You are an financial advisor and you have to analyze the JSON object attached"},
        {"role": "user", "content": "Analyze the follow JSON and consider negative values as expenses and positive as incomes"},
        {"role": "user", "content": prompt}
    ],
    temperature=0.7
)

Thanks in advance!
